# How to integrate ROS with QtQuick GUI

Tags: qt, qtquick2, ros

I am trying to build an User Interface for a robot which is built on ROS-Kinetic.
Now I had the front end made in QtQuick but i am having trouble in backend. Basically , I dont know how to integrate ROS with QtQuick UI . What I expect from my UI is to get the details of nodes , topics , dynamic reconfigure etc in my UI.
So , do anyone have idea regarding some ?

Answer (score 0):

What You Can Do Is Use Sources Of Visualizers Like RVIZ Or RQT and take Whatever You need and put them in One Or More C++ Class And Expose It To QML As An Object And Call It Whenever You Want

Here's [rqt On Github](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt)